# Microsoft Access Expression Builder

Tags: ms-access

I am exploring the various features of microsoft access and stumbled upon the expression builder. I would like to know what syntax language does this expression builder support? I am not sure if it is VBA, SQL or T-SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's neither. Expressions have their own syntax. They can be used also in VBA and in the query design editor, which may cause your confusion.

Here are the essential links:

[Guide to expression syntax](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guide-to-expression-syntax-ebc770bc-8486-4adc-a9ec-7427cce39a90)

[Create an expression](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-expression-893d516c-86f8-43e7-b9c1-d38c02678e5b)

[Examples of expressions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-expressions-D3901E11-C04E-4649-B40B-8B6EC5AED41F)